# Take String Completely Literally in PHP

Tags: php, string

I generated an obfuscated email using the [Hive Logic Enkoder](http://hivelogic.com/enkoder/). I want to echo the result in PHP.

The problem is that it contains `'`, `"`, `\\` and `\\\\`, all of which mess up how PHP reads the string. How can I make PHP take this literally - escape the characters that need escaping, and un-escape the characters that don't?

So I want to:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    <!--
    var x="function f(x){var i,o=\"\",ol=x.length,l=ol;while(x.charCodeAt(l/13)!" +
    "=102){try{x+=x;l+=l;}catch(e){}}for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--){o+=x.charAt(i);}return " +
    "o.substr(0,ol);}f(\")12,\\\",&.=1,p?3k`,gcheB8'Xfo!l720\\\\430\\\\120\\\\>X" +
    "%E220\\\\230\\\\100\\\\530\\\\700\\\\RS,OT130\\\\630\\\\400\\\\230\\\\130\\" +
    "\\530\\\\4[120\\\\700\\\\600\\\\010\\\\300\\\\520\\\\,a038t=68&>&2?120\\\\(" +
    "*\\\"\\\\,v$>%!&+g030\\\\~$$2Wt\\\\I330\\\\400\\\\r\\\\JOGUImi3hu771\\\\tmt" +
    "yq\\\"(f};o nruter};))++y(^)i(tAedoCrahc.x(edoCrahCmorf.gnirtS=+o;721=%y;i=" +
    "+y)12==i(fi{)++i;l<i;0=i(rof;htgnel.x=l,\\\"\\\"=o,i rav{)y,x(f noitcnuf\")" ;
    while(x=eval(x));
    //-->
    //]]>
    </script>
';
```

Edit: here's the function I'm using now:

```
function supportEmail() {
    $str = <<<'EOT'
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        <!--
        var x="function f(x){var i,o=\"\",ol=x.length,l=ol;while(x.charCodeAt(l/13)!" +
        "=102){try{x+=x;l+=l;}catch(e){}}for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--){o+=x.charAt(i);}return " +
        "o.substr(0,ol);}f(\")12,\\\",&.=1,p?3k`,gcheB8'Xfo!l720\\\\430\\\\120\\\\>X" +
        "%E220\\\\230\\\\100\\\\530\\\\700\\\\RS,OT130\\\\630\\\\400\\\\230\\\\130\\" +
        "\\530\\\\4[120\\\\700\\\\600\\\\010\\\\300\\\\520\\\\,a038t=68&>&2?120\\\\(" +
        "*\\\"\\\\,v$>%!&+g030\\\\~$$2Wt\\\\I330\\\\400\\\\r\\\\JOGUImi3hu771\\\\tmt" +
        "yq\\\"(f};o nruter};))++y(^)i(tAedoCrahc.x(edoCrahCmorf.gnirtS=+o;721=%y;i=" +
        "+y)12==i(fi{)++i;l<i;0=i(rof;htgnel.x=l,\\\"\\\"=o,i rav{)y,x(f noitcnuf\")" ;
        while(x=eval(x));
        //-->
        //]]>
        </script>
    EOT;
    echo $str;
}
```

But I get this error returned:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_VARIABLE or T_END_HEREDOC or T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES or T_CURLY_OPEN

Comment: Show how you're reading this string. PHP won't do anything with metachars embedded in a string unless you're running that text somehow, e.g. via eval().

Comment: It sounds like what you want is [nowdocs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc).

Comment: The syntax error is because your ending `EOT;` *must* be at the beginning of its line (i.e.: no whitespace before it and nothing after it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo <<<'EOT'
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    <!--
    var x="function f(x){var i,o=\"\",ol=x.length,l=ol;while(x.charCodeAt(l/13)!" +
    "=102){try{x+=x;l+=l;}catch(e){}}for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--){o+=x.charAt(i);}return " +
    "o.substr(0,ol);}f(\")12,\\\",&.=1,p?3k`,gcheB8'Xfo!l720\\\\430\\\\120\\\\>X" +
    "%E220\\\\230\\\\100\\\\530\\\\700\\\\RS,OT130\\\\630\\\\400\\\\230\\\\130\\" +
    "\\530\\\\4[120\\\\700\\\\600\\\\010\\\\300\\\\520\\\\,a038t=68&>&2?120\\\\(" +
    "*\\\"\\\\,v$>%!&+g030\\\\~$$2Wt\\\\I330\\\\400\\\\r\\\\JOGUImi3hu771\\\\tmt" +
    "yq\\\"(f};o nruter};))++y(^)i(tAedoCrahc.x(edoCrahCmorf.gnirtS=+o;721=%y;i=" +
    "+y)12==i(fi{)++i;l<i;0=i(rof;htgnel.x=l,\\\"\\\"=o,i rav{)y,x(f noitcnuf\")" ;
    while(x=eval(x));
    //-->
    //]]>
    </script>
EOT;
```

Wrap your string in <<<'EOT' EOT;

Comment: Note that `Nowdoc support was added in PHP 5.3.0.`.

Comment: Ah yes, I got confused as I noticed this a while ago. Was thinking of heredoc

Comment: Doesn't it escape a double backslash, as it happens in single-quoted strings?

Comment: @Lumbendil According to the manual, "no parsing is done inside nowdocs". I would assume that to include double backslashes.

Comment: If that's so, you're right, didn't check it... believed that since they where something like a multiline single-quoted string, they'd behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
$str = <<<EOD
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    <!--
    var x="function f(x){var i,o=\"\",ol=x.length,l=ol;while(x.charCodeAt(l/13)!" +
    "=102){try{x+=x;l+=l;}catch(e){}}for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--){o+=x.charAt(i);}return " +
    "o.substr(0,ol);}f(\")12,\\\",&.=1,p?3k`,gcheB8'Xfo!l720\\\\430\\\\120\\\\>X" +
    "%E220\\\\230\\\\100\\\\530\\\\700\\\\RS,OT130\\\\630\\\\400\\\\230\\\\130\\" +
    "\\530\\\\4[120\\\\700\\\\600\\\\010\\\\300\\\\520\\\\,a038t=68&>&2?120\\\\(" +
    "*\\\"\\\\,v$>%!&+g030\\\\~$$2Wt\\\\I330\\\\400\\\\r\\\\JOGUImi3hu771\\\\tmt" +
    "yq\\\"(f};o nruter};))++y(^)i(tAedoCrahc.x(edoCrahCmorf.gnirtS=+o;721=%y;i=" +
    "+y)12==i(fi{)++i;l<i;0=i(rof;htgnel.x=l,\\\"\\\"=o,i rav{)y,x(f noitcnuf\")" ;
    while(x=eval(x));
    //-->
    //]]>
    </script>
EOD;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the string in a file/database, and from there obtain it from there.

The problem from using nowdocs/heredocs commented in the other answers is that \\ is an escaped slash in both of them.

You can also use a nowdoc block and replace all occurrence of \ to \\.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is giving this error is because there is white space before the closing EOT. Remove all tabs or white space in front or behind it.